# ssh и publickey: использование нескольких наборов ключей

Tags: git, github, ssh, ssh-key

События развивались так:

на домашнем компе я пользовался github, настроив авторизацию по ключам, и разместив ключи в `%userprofile%/.ssh`. В этой директории лежали сгенерированные мной файлы id_rsa и id_rsa.pub, а также пара файлов конфигурации.

Затем мне понадобилось настроить рабочее место для дистанционной работы.

При этом мне надо поместить в эту же директорию еще пару `ключ-публичный ключ`, которые позволяют мне авторизовываться на рабочих серверах.

Пока я обхожусь так: я переименовываю директорию `%userprofile%/.ssh`, и у меня на компе есть два набора: "рабочие пары ключ-открытый ключ" и "личные пары ключ-открытый ключ".

А как делать это правильно? Можно ли использовать несколько ключей одновременно? правильно ли я понимаю, что только явное указание ключа в команде `ssh -i id_rsa ...` позволяет указывать, каким именно ключем надо авторизовываться в том или ином случае?

Спасибо заранее за Ваши советы.

Comment: Просто вместо `id_rsa` выбрать любое другое имя? Чтобы явно не указывать нужный ключ каждый раз, можно прописать соответствие ключей хостам в `.ssh/config` https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/SSH_keys#Managing_multiple_keys

Comment: Или воспользоваться ssh-агентом. Вообще он в линуксах есть по умолчанию

Answer (score 1):

Дайте (скопируйте) понятные имена ключей. Пропишите в файл `config` все настройки.

~/.ssh/config :

```
Host work
  HostName 123.45.67.89
  Port 12345
  User workuser
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_work
  IdentitiesOnly yes

host github
  HostName github.com
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_github
  User git
  IdentitiesOnly yes
```

И используйте просто :

```
ssh work [ команды ]

git команды
```

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ. я более чем уверен, что для более толкового человека, чем я, этот ответ был бы идеален. К моему сожалению, мне он не помог. Причина такова: вот я беру с рабочего компьютера 4 файла (2 пары ключей). Помещаю их в пустой каталог .ssh на домашнем компе. Делаю git pull. Система задаёт мне один вопрос - насчет помещения записи в файл known_hosts, и потом всё магически работает. Если я переименую ключи в процессе копирования - работать не будет, с ошибкой "Could not read from remote repository...". Но спасибо за ответ!

Comment: а почему переименовывать вы стали в процессе? У вас две пары с разными именами (*каталогами*). Можно работать параллельно.

Comment: ну в общем, я так и стал делать, как и написал в вопросе. Теперь у меня два каталога с ключами.

Comment: так что у вас не работает? вы сделали в конфигурации нужные пути на ключи? `IdentityFile ~/.ssh/каталогA/id_rsa` и `IdentityFile ~/.ssh/каталогB/id_rsa`